# php how to allow some in a folder and not allow others in that folder

Tags: .htaccess, directory

- I am hosting my website on hostmonster.com.
- I am using php/mysql.
- I have a folder with pdf files: *pfdfolder/*.
- I want to give access to some users to that folder and deny access to other users to that folder. How do I go about it ?

I don't know if it helps but I have a mysql with username and passwords if maybe I can use that.

Comment: What does this have to do with PHP? Do you want to write an interface for this folder WITH php and users with a certain login can see the files?

Comment: I informed those who saw my question what I am dealing with. I am new to this.

Comment: @IgorGhidora How many PDF files do you have there? How many should allowed to how many users? or How many should deny to how many users? It's important to choose a feasible solution ...

Comment: ok I will have different number of pdf(s). For example. User "george" can only access pdf1 pdf2 pdf3. User "mike" can only access pdf4 pdf5 and so on. Assuming one-to-one (user-file). I can even be confortable if instead of pdf files there would be folders in which the pdfs will be store. Say george can access folder1 only, and mike can access folder2 only. Thx for the fast responses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have a session based login system, you could use something like .htaccess

http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess3.shtml

Comment: I do have a session based login system. I don't know how to use that.

Comment: @IgorGhidora Are you using a CMS or ready-made script on your website? If yes, which one?

Comment: @IgorGhidora You mean you are using a CMS software? So what's the name of that?

Comment: I hope I understood everything correct. I have Dreamweaver 5.5 where I am connected with my website, and using Dreamweaver I write php files etc. Let me know if I got your question wrong.

Comment: I used the .htpasswd to do that. for each folder. It works good. THx